Label-Studio error when importing local image files
I'm trying annotate some jpg images from my local machine with label-studio. The images import fine at first, but the image icons don't show up in the tasks. If I select a task to annotate, I am met with this error:
There was an issue loading URL from $image value

Things to look out for:

URL is valid
URL scheme matches the service scheme, i.e. https and https
The static server has wide-open CORS
Technical description:
URL: /data/upload/16/7ad900c6-Tank_4_P1-1_S7-1_cropped.jpg

All of the URLS I imported were from the same directory as the one described above.
Any way I can solve this error? Or is it just a bug that needs to be fixed?
Thank you!
